# Find a positive sequence so that $\sum\frac{1}{n^{1+\varepsilon_{n}}}$ converges

Tags: sequences-and-series

Find a positive sequence $(\varepsilon_{n})_{n=1}^{\infty}$ so that $\underset{n\to\infty}{\lim}\varepsilon_{n}=0$ and $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^{1+\varepsilon_{n}}}$ converges.

I tried using the condensation test:

$\frac{2^{n}}{(2^{n})^{1+\varepsilon_{2^{n}}}}=\frac{2^{n}}{2^{n+n\varepsilon_{2^{n}}}}=\frac{1}{2^{n\varepsilon_{2^{n}}}}$

and from here tried to get to a converging sequence: $\frac{1}{2^{n\cdot\log_{2}\sqrt[n]{n^{2}}}}=\frac{1}{(\sqrt[n]{n^{2}})^{n}}=\frac{1}{n^{2}}$, but that doesn't seem to help as $\sum\frac{1}{n^{1+\log_{2}\sqrt[n]{n^{2}}}}$ diverges.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take $\epsilon_n=\frac {2 \ln (\ln n)} {ln n}$ for $n \geq 2$ and $\epsilon_1=1$. Then $n^{1+\epsilon_n}=e^{(1+\epsilon_n) ln n}=n (ln n)^{2}$ and $\sum_{n=2}^{\infty} \frac 1 {n(\ln n)^{2}} <\infty$.

Comment: I don't see how $e^(1+\varepsilon )lnn = 1/n(ln^2 n)$. Wolfram says its $n(log^2 n)$

Comment: @Parasect Sorry, that was  a typo.

Comment: Oh, that got me confused at first. Thanks!